# mostrar datos de 2 tablas en la vista edit de laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

buenas compañeros estoy incursionando en el framework de laravel resulta que tengo mi vista de editar y tengo datos de 2 tablas pero no he podido lograr visualizar los datos de ambas espero me puedan ayudar se los agradeceria

tengo la tabla invoices y la tabla provider
en la tabla invoices estoy guardando el id del proveedor que se llama provid alli guardo el id del proveedor seleccionado en el create
en mi controlador tengo esto

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $categorias=Providers::find($id);
         $rowws = InvoiceTemp::latest()->get();
        $row = Invoiceorder::find($id);
        $files= InvoiceorderProduct::where('id_invoice', $id)->get()->toArray();
        return view('invoiceorder.edit', compact('id', 'row','files','rowws','categorias'));
    }
```

en vista edit tengo esto

```
 <form action="{{url('invoiceorder/'.$row->id)}}" method="post" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
 
  @csrf
                  
<br>
<div class="box">

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="inputState">Type</label>
      <select id="inputState" name="provid" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled readonly>{{$categorias['name']}}</option>
        
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    
 
              <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="sinborde" type="text" id="type" value="{{$categorias['type']}}" name="type"style="width: 250px">
                 </div>  

             </div>
             <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="sinborde" type="text" id="address" value="{{$categorias['address']}}" name="address" readonly style="width: 250px" >
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
             <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="sinborde" type="text"  id="email" value="{{$categorias['email']}}" name="email" readonly style="width: 250px" >
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
            <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="sinborde" type="text" id="telephone" value="{{$categorias['telephone']}}" name="telephone" readonly style="width: 250px" >
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
             <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
                  
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="sinborde" type="text" id="products" value="{{$categorias['products']}}" name="products" readonly style="width: 250px" >
                 </div>  
                 
             </div>
 
</div>
```

y segun o que lei tengo la union de las tablas asi

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoiceorder extends Model
{
    protected $table='invoiceorder';

    protected $fillable=['type','provid','ordern', 'date',  'sub_total','tax',
    'tax_amount','total_amount'];

    public function providers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\providers');
    }


}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Providers extends Model
{
    protected $fillable= ['type', 'name', 'address','contactper','contactlang','vat', 'email',  
    'telephone', 'products','textarea','type_ev','evaluation_date','evaluation_int','next','status','upload','textarea_eve','content'];

    // public function user()
    // {
    //     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    // }
    public function invoiceorder()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\InvoiceOrder');
    }

}
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: No termino de entender cual es tu duda

Comment: que en el edit no logro ver los datos de mi tabla de providers

Comment: veo varias entidades involucradas, existe alguna relación entre ellas? lo pregunto por que veo varias consultas y tal vez se resuelva con una sola y de ahi mandar la info a tu vista

Comment: de hecho la que dice rowws=invoicetemp es solo para mostrar un dato esa no se toca para nada las otras consultas estan bien me funcionan perfecto invoiceorder e invoiceproduct si estan relacionadas ya que ne invoice order estan los datos de la orden y en el invoiceorderproduct esta la informacion de los productos lo hize asi debido a que como son varios productos(arreglo) necesitaba asociarlos a la misma factura